# std::set< struct > sorted by property value in struct c++

Tags: c++, struct, stl, set

I have this struct:

```
struct abc {
    int x, y;
    char s[20];
};

bool comp(abc a, abc b) {
    int n = strlen(a.s), m = strlen(b.s);
    for(int i = 0; i < min(n,m); i++)
        if(a.s[i] != b.s[i])
            return a.s[i] < b.s[i];
    return n < m;
}
```

I want to make a set with this structs sorted by `s[]` , but I don't know how.

Comment: Either use your `comp` function when creating your [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set), or instead make an `operator<` function for your type.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg give me an example how use comp function when I create the std::set because I don't know how to write , sorry for my bad english

Comment: Either follow the link in my previous comment and look at e.g. the constructor, or go to your favorite search engine and search for e.g. "c++ set custom compare"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to overload `operator<` for your structure. Any standard algorithm/container that wants to compare their sort order will use that by default.

```
bool operator<(abc const & a, abc const & b) {
    // your code here
}
```

Alternatively, you can specify your comparator just for the set:

```
std::set<abc, bool(*)(abc,abc)> my_set(comp);
```

This would be a bit more convenient with a function class rather than a function:

```
struct comp {
    bool operator()(abc const & a, abc const & b) {
        // your code here
    }
};

std::set<abc, comp> my_set;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the < operator for abc so that stl knows how to compare two instances of abc.
So how do you compare two members of a struct that have 3 fields? Use [lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

Here is the practical implementation of your example.

```
struct abc {
    int x, y;
    char s[20];

   const bool operator < ( const abc &r ) const{
        return ( x< r.x)
               ||(( x== r.x) && ( y< r.y))
               ||(( x== r.x) && ( y== r.y) && strcmp(s,r.s)<0) ;
    }
};
```

Then the set is **automatically sorted** when you insert in it.